# SQL server pivot multiple columns to multiple rows and including nulls

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Student   Class1    Class1_score  Class2   Class2_score   Class3.... |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Alex      English   70            Maths    100            NULL       |
| John      Science   50            NULL     NULL           NULL       |
| Bruce     Maths     50            Science  50             English    |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Which i want to pivot to something like the following:

```
+--------------------------+
| Student   Class    Score |
+--------------------------+
| Alex      English   70   |
| Alex      Maths     100  |
| Alex      Science   NULL |
| Alex      History   NULL |
| John      English   NULL |
+--------------------------+
```

Which includes NULL for classes that are not in the original table for that particular student (e.g. Science for Alex)

How can I achieve this in SQL?

Comment: **`mysql` <> `sql-server`** Tag the relevant rdbms

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that class type occurs only once in the `classX` columns:

```
select student,
       'English' class,
       coaslesce(case when class1 = 'english' then Class1_score end, 
                 case when class2 = 'english' then Class2_score end,
                 case when class3 = 'english' then Class3_score end,
                 case when class4 = 'english' then Class4_score end) score
from your_table

union

select student,
       'Maths' class,
       coaslesce(case when class1 = 'Maths' then Class1_score end, 
                 case when class2 = 'Maths' then Class2_score end,
                 case when class3 = 'Maths' then Class3_score end,
                 case when class4 = 'Maths' then Class4_score end) score
from your_table

union

select student,
       'Science' class,
       coaslesce(case when class1 = 'Science' then Class1_score end, 
                 case when class2 = 'Science' then Class2_score end,
                 case when class3 = 'Science' then Class3_score end,
                 case when class4 = 'Science' then Class4_score end) score
from your_table

union

select student,
       'History' class,
       coaslesce(case when class1 = 'History' then Class1_score end, 
                 case when class2 = 'History' then Class2_score end,
                 case when class3 = 'History' then Class3_score end,
                 case when class4 = 'History' then Class4_score end) score
from your_table
```

Comment: We don't need to aggregate by student here.  That would be appropriate for a pivot, not an unpivot.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen you are right, I have updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the `Class` column values should come for each `Student` column value, then declare 2 table variables, one for storing unique values of `Student` column values and other for storing unique values of `Class` column values. Then do a full outer join between these two tables and use this result set as a subset and join it with another table variable which contains separate rows for each `student` each `class` and `score`. And all these can be done by executing dynamic SQL query.

**Query**

```
-- table variabe to store unique class values

declare @sql as varchar(max) = 'declare @tbl_class as table([class] varchar(100));'
                             + 'insert into @tbl_class([class]) ';
select @sql += stuff((
        select ' union select [' + [column_name] + '] from [' + [table_name] + '] '
        + 'where [' + [column_name] + '] is not null'
        from information_schema.columns
        where [table_name] = 'your_table_name'
        and [column_name] like 'class%[0-9]'
        order by [ordinal_position]
        for xml path('')
    )
    , 1, 7, ''
) + ';';

-- table variabe to store unique student values

select @sql += 'declare @tbl_student as table([student] varchar(100));'
            + 'insert into @tbl_student([student]) '
            + 'select distinct [Student] from [your_table_name];';

-- table variable to store student score and class values one by one

select @sql += 'declare @tbl_scores as table'
            + '([student] varchar(100), [class] varchar(100), [score] int);'
            + 'insert into @tbl_scores([student], [class], [score]) ';

select @sql += stuff((
        select ' union all select [Student], ' 
        + '[' + t.[col_1] + '] as [class],'  
        + '[' + t.[col_2] + '] as [score] '
        + 'from [' + t.[table_name] + '] '
        from (
            select [column_name] as [col_1], [column_name] + '_score' as [col_2], 
            [ordinal_position], [table_name]
            from information_schema.columns
            where [table_name] = 'your_table_name'
            and [column_name] like 'class%[0-9]'
        ) t
        order by t.[ordinal_position]
        for xml path('')
    )
    , 1, 10, ''
) + ';';

-- final result

select @sql += 'select t.[student], t.[Class], tsc.[Score] from('
            + 'select ts.[student], tc.[Class]'
            + ' from @tbl_student as ts '
            + ' full outer join @tbl_class as tc '
            + 'on 1 = 1 ) t '
            + 'left join @tbl_scores as tsc '
            + 'on t.[student] = tsc.[student] '
            + 'and t.[Class] = tsc.[Class];';

exec(@sql);
```

**[Find a demo here](http://rextester.com/STSCC4693)**

Answer (score 0):

You are actually looking for unpivot (wide to tall), rather than pivot.  One approach which should work across almost any database uses a series of unions:

```
SELECT Student, Class, Score
FROM
(
    SELECT Student, Class1 AS Class, Class1_score AS Score, 1 AS position
    FROM yourTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Student, Class2, Class2_score, 2
    FROM yourTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Student, Class3, Class3_score, 3
    FROM yourTable
) t
ORDER BY
    Student, position;
```

Comment: I believe that NULL rows are not added in your solution

Comment: @RadimBača I disagree with your comment and with your answer.

Comment: ok, but how the `'john','english', null` row can occur in your result?

Answer (score 0):

Sample data

```
 IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.tempdata') IS NOT NULL

DROP TABLE tempdata
;With cte(Student ,  Class1 ,   Class1_score,  Class2,   Class2_score,   Class3,Class3_score)
AS
(
SELECT 'Alex' ,'English', 70,'Maths'   , 100 ,  NULL    ,NULL   UNION ALL
SELECT 'John' ,'Science', 50,NULL      ,NULL ,  NULL    ,NULL   UNION ALL
SELECT 'Bruce','Maths'  , 50,'Science' , 50  , 'English',NULL
)
SELECT * INTO tempdata FROM cte

SELECT * FROM tempdata
```

By Using Cross apply and dynamic SQL

```
DECLARE @DynamicColumns NVARCHAR(max)
        ,@Sql NVARCHAR(max)

;WITH cte
AS
(
SELECT  COLUMN_NAME, 
        DENSE_RANK()OVER(ORDER BY SUBSTRING(COLUMN_NAME,0,7)) As BatchNo
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='tempdata' AND COLUMN_NAME <>'Student'
 )
SELECT @DynamicColumns=STUFF((SELECT ', '+ReqCol FROM
     (
        SELECT   
             DISTINCT '('+STUFF((SELECT  ', '+COLUMN_NAME 
            FROM CTE i WHERE i.BatchNo=o.BatchNo
            FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'') + ')' AS ReqCol
        FROM cte o
 )dt
 FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'')


SET @Sql='SELECT  Student
                 ,Class
                 ,Score 
        FROM tempdata
             CROSS APPLY (VALUES '+@DynamicColumns+'
                        ) As Dt (Class, Score)
            WHERE Class IS NOT NULL

'

PRINT @Sql
EXEC (@Sql)
```

Result

```
Student Class   Score
---------------------
Alex    English 70
Alex    Maths   100
John    Science 50
Bruce   Maths   50
Bruce   Science 50
Bruce   English NULL
```